# Encode special characters in cshtml

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, encodeuricomponent

I have a razor view which has a hidden field `Model.Token`. The `Token` consist of special characters. This `Token` is appended to a link in href.

```
<a href='http://localhost.com?token=@Model.Token'>Link</a>
```

If Model.Token has a `+`, the link renders it as a blank space. That is, if

```
Model.Token = 'ABC+DE'
```

The link becomes

```
http://localhost.com?token=ABC DE
```

How do I encode the `Token` in the link so that `+` is not removed? Do I need to use have a js and use `encodeURI`, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the System.Uri

```
<a href='http://localhost.com?token=@Uri.EscapeUriString(Model.Token)'>Link</a>
```